# How to offset window top 50%

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/dKDJz/6/

I'm trying to fix position a div to top 50% off my window height. Which I can do fine with CSS.

But the original position of this 'div.slider-button' is absolute positioned further down the page. But as the page scrolls down, and when the 'div.slider-button' reaches the 50% offset top position, my `.fixed` class should be added.

Currently my script below, adds the `.fixed` class when my div reaches window top position.

I need the script to add my `.fixed` class when my 'div.slider-button' reaches 50% of the window height.

```
var $window    = $(window),
    $button    = $(".slider-button"),           
    offsetbut  = $button.offset();

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offsetbut.top ) {
        $button.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $button.removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

```
.fixed { 
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 50% !important;
}
```

See jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/dKDJz/6/

You can see when the arrow reaches the top, it snaps to the middle, the arrow just needs to reache the middle of the window and stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the example here http://jsfiddle.net/dKDJz/7/

It is working correctly as far as moving once the window reaches 50% but it was going off the top of the window and not when the arrow reached the middle.  I've added in `-($window.height()/2)` so that it takes into account the size of the window and to go off when the arrow reaches the center.  Hope that made sense:)

Comment: I love you. Makes perfect sense. Thanks